# Remove the string from left and right side of date using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
string = "I went to market on October 29,2017I"
12-7-2021mma  --->12-7-2021
kk12/7/2021   ---> 12-7-2021
yy12/9/2021kko  ---> 12/9/2021
```

Is there any solution to get "I went to market on October 29,2017" by removing "I" from October 29,2017I

There are much more cases like above

Comment: Do you know all the data formats that appear in your data? Because you've already shown three different kinds and you'll probably have to try all possible patterns on each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dparser`:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

s = "I went to market on October 29,2017I"
print(dparser.parse(s,fuzzy=True))
```

OUTPUT:

```
2021-10-29 00:00:00
```

EDIT:

If you want the month in a specific format:

```
s = "I went to market on October 29,2017I"
out = str(dparser.parse(s,fuzzy=True)).split(" ")[0]
print(out)

import datetime
print (datetime.datetime.strptime(out,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%B %d, %Y'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
October 29, 2017
```

Comment: Is there any way to update as new string like "I went to market on October 29,2017" after removing "I" from the date

Comment: @Ajay that should be a separate question. Please ask it as a separate question once your current question is answered.